# Error installing php-soap on PHP 5.4.20 Centos 6

Tags: php, soap

I am trying to install php-soap on my Centos 6.6. I am running PHP 5.4.20. When I do a "yum install php-soap" I get this error:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: centos.openitc.uk
* epel: epel.check-update.co.uk
* extras: centos.openitc.uk
* rpmforge: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net
* updates: centos.openitc.uk
* webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-soap.x86_64 0:5.3.3-40.el6_6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6 for package: php-soap-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-soap-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6
       Installed: php-common-5.4.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.20-1.el6.remi
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-38.el6.x86_64 (base)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-38.el6
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6
       Available: php54w-common-5.4.36-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.36-1.w6
       Available: php54w-common-5.4.37-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.37-1.w6
       Available: php54w-common-5.4.38-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.38-1.w6
       Available: php55w-common-5.5.20-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.20-1.w6
       Available: php55w-common-5.5.21-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.21-1.w6
       Available: php55w-common-5.5.22-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.22-1.w6
       Available: php56w-common-5.6.4-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.4-1.w6
       Available: php56w-common-5.6.5-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.5-1.w6
       Available: php56w-common-5.6.6-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.6-1.w6
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

How do I work around it? I have these PHP modules installed:

```
php-tcpdf-dejavu-sans-fonts-6.2.4-1.el6.noarch
newrelic-php5-4.18.0.89-1.x86_64
php-cli-5.4.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64
php-mcrypt-5.4.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64
php-gd-5.4.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64
phpMyAdmin-4.0.7-1.el6.remi.noarch
php-pear-1.9.4-4.el6.noarch
php-tcpdf-6.2.4-1.el6.noarch
php-common-5.4.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64
php-mbstring-5.4.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64
php-bcmath-5.4.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64
php-pdo-5.4.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64
php-pecl-memcache-3.0.8-1.el6.remi.x86_64
php-php-gettext-1.0.11-3.el6.noarch
newrelic-php5-common-4.18.0.89-1.noarch
php-xml-5.4.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64
php-mysql-5.4.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64
php-recode-5.4.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64
php-tidy-5.4.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64
php-5.4.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64
```

Is it an idea to remove PHP 5.4 and install PHP 5.3.3? I am not sure if my sites can run PHP 5.5.

Thanks for any suggestions!!

Comment: Please check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27866607/installing-php-soap-with-yum-and-pear-both-fail

Comment: Thanks I think that will solve my problem. Do you know if it is good to install PHP from webtatic ?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the link from @liquidflo and I did this to solve the problem.

- Listed all PHP modules installed to make sure I got back everything later

  rpm -qa | grep php

I had a mix of modules I think from 5.3 and 5.4 Then I copied all the names of the modules and removed them with

```
#sudo yum remove php php-mbstring php-mysql php-cli php-gd ...(list all the modules...
```

Then I did an install of all the removed php modules.

```
#sudo yum install php php-mbstring php-mysql php-cli php-gd php-soap ...(list all the modules, added php-soap now)...
```

I am now back on PHP 5.3.3 and php-soap works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download this..

[php soap 5.4.16-36 i686](ftp://ftp.icm.edu.pl/vol/rzm5/linux-centos-altarch/7.2.1511/updates/i386/Packages/php-soap-5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.i686.rpm)

And force installation..

```
rpm -Uvh php-soap-5.4.16-36.1.el7_2.1.i686.rpm --nodeps
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be the conflict between php version and soap version getting from remi repository,

Below command list the available packages from repository,

```
yum list php55-*
```

Here 55 is the php version.

```
...
php55-php-snmp.x86_64                                                    5.5.38-7.el6.remi                                            remi-safe
php55-php-soap.x86_64                                                    5.5.38-7.el6.remi                                            remi-safe
php55-php-suhosin.x86_64                                                 0.9.38-1.el6.remi                                            remi-safe
...
```

Find out the relevant package and run it.

```
yum install php55-php-soap.x86_64
```

Finally you have to enable the soap module,

```
find -name soap.so
/opt/remi/php55/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/soap.so
```

Add the below line into the **php.ini** file,

```
extension='/opt/remi/php55/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/soap.so'
```

Restart the apache server,

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

Comment: NO, bad idea. don't mix php 5.4 and 5.5 extensions, don't mix php55-php* (SCL, multiple versions) and php-* (single version)

Comment: I have given the php55 for example, you can replace with your actual php version (php54 or whatever)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>    Installed: php-common-5.4.20-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
> ```

You have php 5.4 from "remi" repository, so you need to enable this repository to install additional extension (btw, this will imply an update to latest 5.4.45).

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install php-soap
```

You can also permanently enable the php 5.4 repository  (or any other version)

```
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php54
yum install php-soap
```

Notice: [PHP 5.4 is now EOL](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2015/10/05/PHP-5.4-is-dead), and unmaintained by the PHP Project, I strongly you update to a [maintained version](http://php.net/supported-versions.php) (5.6, 7, 7.1).

See  the [Wizard instructions](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/)