# Error when trying to install php soap

Tags: php, soap

I get error when I try to install soap via the command:

```
yum install php-soap
```

The error is:

```
Error: Package: php-soap-5.3.3-46.el6_7.1.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-46.el6_7.1
       Installed: php-common-5.4.26-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.26-1.el6.remi
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (base)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-46.el6_6
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_7.1.x86_64 (updates)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-46.el6_7.1
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/44017242/4453058

Answer (score 2):

**php-common** is installed from **remi**, which is not enabled by default, so you need to enable it to find additional extensions

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install php-soap
```

While PHP 5.4 is still available, it is EOL (un-maintained upstream), so I recommend to use 5.5 or 5.6.

See the [Configuration Wizard](http://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/)

Answer (score 0):

You have PHP 5.4 installed. Remi dropped that out of his repo [when 5.4 reached EOL](http://blog.remirepo.net/post/2016/02/04/PHP-version-5.5.32-5.6.18-and-7.0.3).

> **PHP version 5.4 have reached its end of life and is no longer maintained by the project**. Given the very important number of downloads by the users of my repository the version is still available in  remi repository for Enterprise Linux (RHEL, CentOS...) and includes  security fix (from version 5.5.31). The upgrade to a maintained version is strongly recommended. (A new version with security fix from 5.5.32 should  be soon available)

Since the repo no longer has 5.4, it's trying to install 5.3 from the base repo. You need to upgrade to 5.5 or later to get the library you want.

Comment: `yum update php` should do it. I would recommend going to 5.6 if you can

Comment: Yes, PHP 5.4 is EOL, but not dropped from "remi" repository, see http://blog.remirepo.net/post/2015/10/05/PHP-5.4-is-dead